# Python unable to get child tag and its value from parent tag in XML

Tags: python, xml, minidom

In Python, I m using **from xml.dom import minidom** module.
Further, I have an xml, trying to parse it using the above module.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites tests="4" failures="2">
    <testsuite name="iOSUITests" tests="4" failures="2" time="9325.715">
        <testcase classname="DR" name="test_1()" time="26.1042">
        </testcase>
        <testcase classname="DR" name="test_2()" time="31.5843">
        </testcase>
        <testcase classname="DR" name="test_3()" time="32.8958">
            <failure message="failed - reason1">
            </failure>
        </testcase>
        <testcase classname="GD" name="test_4()" time="48.18003">
            <failure message="failed - reason2">
            </failure>
        </testcase>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

I m trying to get failure child tag of each test case but unable to get it for the corresponding test case. As i need to update test case status as Pass or Fail and its message. I tried to execute my below code.

```
testcase = doc.getElementsByTagName("testcase")
for index, tc in enumerate(testcase):
xml_testcase_list.append({})
xml_testcase_list[index][classname] = tc.getAttribute(classname)
#print "tc.firstChild.items()", tc.childNodes.item
#print "tc.firstChild.items()", tc.firstChild.nodeValue
if 'failure' in tc.firstChild.nodeValue:
    xml_testcase_list[index][failure] = []
    failure = doc.getElementsByTagName("failure")[0]
    #print "getNodeText(failure)", failure.childNodes
    for each_index, each_failure in enumerate(failure):
        xml_testcase_list[index][failure].append({})
        xml_testcase_list[index][failure][each_index][message] = each_failure.getAttribute(message)
```

How can i get a failure tag in my if condition?

Comment: use elementTree. he is faster and can help you get atributes, text and all child tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all `failure` child tags of a `testcase` element, if any exists, you can call `tc.getElementsByTagName("failure")`. If you use that method on an element, it will only inspect children. Then you can check if the array returned is empty, and get the first result if it's not.

```
from xml.dom import minidom

with open('xml.xml') as f:  # your file stored in xml.xml
    doc = minidom.parse(f)

testcase = doc.getElementsByTagName("testcase")
xml_testcase_list = []
for index, tc in enumerate(testcase):
    xml_testcase_list.append({})
    xml_testcase_list[index]['classname'] = tc.getAttribute('classname')
    failures = tc.getElementsByTagName('failure')
    if failures:
        xml_testcase_list[index][failure] = []
        failure = failures[0]
        for each_index, each_failure in enumerate(failure):
            xml_testcase_list[index][failure].append({})
            xml_testcase_list[index][failure][each_index][message] = each_failure.getAttribute(message)
    else:
        print 'no failures for', tc
```

I have to say that your example does not include any child elements of `failure`, so the `for each_index, each_failure` will not work as intended.

Comment: I have removed the 'failure = failures[0]' because we are using the for loop in the end. Above information helped.

Answer (score 0):

The challenge is not the if condition, its the way you are referencing your tags:

```
xml_testcase_list[index][classname] = tc.getAttribute(classname)
```

should be

```
xml_testcase_list[index]['classname'] = tc.getAttribute('classname')
```

Also please send your error message.

Comment: classname was defined in the __init__ , which i didnt mention and i removed the self.